# Selenium Webdriver "Expectedconditions.not" is not working as expected

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, selenium-webdriver, wait

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60)

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Loading...')]"));
System.out.println("Test");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Loading...')]"))));
System.out.println("Test");
```

Trying to wait for the page loading to be completed. The first "test" is printed in the console and below exception is printed on exceuting the wait.until statement.
Even after the loading screen is gone the wait.until is still waiting.
Already tried Staleness of the element also and does not work, getting the same timeout exception.
Once the loading is completed the element is no more available in the DOM

Answer (score 12):

When you want to wait for element to be not present, instead of `presenceOfElementLocated` use `presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy`:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.not(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Loading...')]"))));
```

It will wait until there are no elements on the page that fit the locator.

Answer (score 4):

you are not waiting for the element to be visible in the first statement,i.e,

> WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Loading...')]"));

i think this is causing the `NoSuchElementException`...
you can try the following :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Loading...')]")));

new WebDriverWait(driver,60).until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Loading...')]")));
```

the above code will **first wait for the visibility of the element,and then its invisibility.**

Comment: I had already tried this the first statement works fine but the second statement keeps on waiting for a full 60 secs even after loading element is gone, So here I end up waiting a full 60 secs.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)).Until(d => d.FindElement(By.Id("searchTextBox0")).Displayed)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'll be using this multiple times, create a method. E.g. if you'll be waiting for other elements elsewhere.

```
public void waitForElementToBeVisible(String xpath) throws Throwable {
    try {
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.or(
                ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpath))
        ));
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Timeout exceeded");
        driver.close();
    }
}
```

You can then call this method multiple times. To call the one you're stuck with it would be

```
waitForElementToBeVisible("//div[contains(text(),'Loading...')]");
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you need to do is wait for the page to load, you can execute a Javascript function to check page load has completed:

```
String val = "";
do {
    val = (String)((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return document.readyState");
    // DO WHATEVER
} while (!"complete".equals(val));
```

When using `findElement()` you must use implicit wait before attempting to locate the element. Otherwise, `NoSuchElementException` could be thrown if the component is not loaded on the page:

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS); // Blocks NoSuchElementExceptions for 5 seconds when findElement() is called (set for the duration of driver's life.
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Loading...')]"));
```

That strategy should be used judiciously as it will most likely affect the performance of your tests. Alternatively, you should use `WebDriverWait` (explicit wait):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Loading...')]"))); // Presence of component checks the existence of the element in the DOM which it will always be true
System.out.println("Testing visibility passed...");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.invisibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//div[contains(text(),'Loading...')]"))); // Presence of component checks the existence of the element in the DOM which it will always be true
System.out.println("Testing invisibility passed...");
```

Be aware that on the last strategy, `visibilityOfElementLocated` returns a `WebElement` and `visibilityOfElementLocated` returns a `Boolean`. Therefore, you cannot chain the conditions by using `.andThen(Function)`.